# How To Include Breadcrumb Module On A Component for Joomla 1.6

Tags: module, joomla, components, joomla1.6

I have a custom component that requires the standard Joomla breadcrumb module.  I tried using the following and it didn't do anything:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-2" />
```

Keep in mind this code came from the template index file and I am trying to integrate the module into a custom component

Answer (score 2):

That is not how to do it. This is for use in Joomla templates to include the module position. You need to make the breadcrumbs programmatically from within your component. See this tutorial on how to do this: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_breadcrumbs

**NB: Once you have done this ensure that you have the breadcrumbs module published and the position is set correctly for your specific template.**

This link will also be useful - http://docs.joomla.org/JPathway/1.6

**[EDIT]**

Try add this in your view.html.php for your component:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$pathway = $app->getPathway();
$pathway->addItem('Google', 'http://www.google.com');
```

This will add a breadcrumb that says "Google" and when clicked will link to www.google.com

In terms of creating your breadcrumbs you need to use your url to determine how far you are into you component e.g. "Home // Category // Weblinks" would have a url like:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_weblinks&cid=2:dogs&id=54:link-to-google
```

cid = 2 tells us that we are at least in the category, so we can add a breadcrumb for this.

id = 54 tells us we are looking at a weblink so we can add a breadcrumb for the page before which is the list of weblinks within the category

Comment: That's just it.  I don't want it on the template files.  I just want it on a specific component only.  I checked out the tutorial, but it doesn't provide any insight on how to add the breadcrumb to the component itself.  You mentioned that I need to programatically make the breadcrumbs, but I ran into an error "Fatal error: Call to undefined method ContentModelFeatured::getData()" so it either doesn't work or won't work for Joomla 1.6  Please advise..

Comment: You are definitely doing something wrong. Try the edit I made in my answer above.

Comment: All that does is add a new pathway.  That's not what I need.  For example, when I added the google pathway, it didn't display anything, but when I added the breadcrumb snippet (in my question), it showed the breadcrumb with Google at the end.  When I all I want is to have the breadcrumb as is to display in my component itself and not alter it from my component in any way.

Comment: If you want to see the breadcrumbs module then you need to publish it and set it to the correct template position. You can do this from the backend on Joomla. Ensure to make the module available on all pages.